# cat results of grep

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I am trying to concatenate the results of my grep search.
my grep search finds about 4 files on my system and outputs them in a new line for each file. I thought by passing this information to `tr '\n' ' '` I would get all of the files from the search on one line and then pass it to `cat > bigfile` to have big file contain all of the files content from my search. Instead `bigfile` just contains the list of files that grep found.

How do I make `bigfile` contain a concatenation of all of the files that grep found.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
egrep -Rl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | tr '\n' ' ' | cat > bigfile
```

and then `bigfile` contains:

```
/home/moose/test/file1 /home/moose/test/2 /home/moose/test/3 /home/moose/moose/file4
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to concatenate the *contents* of the matching files into a single `bigfile`, then you need to pass the filenames to `cat` as distinct arguments: you could do that with `xargs`

```
egrep -ZRl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | xargs -0 cat
```

The addition of the `-Z` and `-0` flags passes the names using null delimiters, allowing the command to work with any legal filenames (including those containing whitespace or newlines).

Answer (score 1):

1. `cat` does nothing here.  Simply redirecting the output of `tr` is effectively the same as piping it to `cat` and redirecting.
2. Try `paste` instead of `tr`.  For example:

   `egrep -Rl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | paste -sd' ' > bigfile`
3. `xargs` works too, and has the advantage of splitting the output into multiple lines if/when it reaches the maximum length of a command-line:

   `egrep -Rl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | xargs > bigfile`

BTW, why does it even matter if the files are listed one per line or all on one line?  If you intend to use it in the command line of another program or as input to a `for` or `while` loop, you're probably better off with one filename per line anyway, especially if there's any files with space characters in the filename.

Comment: The way I read it, the questioner is trying to concatenate the *contents* of the matching files - something like `egrep -ZRl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | xargs -0 cat` perhaps?

Comment: the example output shows a list of filenames, all on one line....but, yeah, if your interpretation is correct, `xargs cat` will do the job, and null-terminated filenames are perfect.  You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` with -`s` (serialize) option to get all the lines in a single one.

In your case:

```
grep .... | paste -sd'\t'
```

Here, `-t` indicates delimiter, using tab here as the delimiter, change it to fit your need.

**Example:**

```
% printf 'foo\nbar\nspam\negg\n'               
foo
bar
spam
egg

% printf 'foo\nbar\nspam\negg\n' | paste -sd' ' 
foo bar spam egg

% printf 'foo\nbar\nspam\negg\n' | paste -sd'\t'
foo   bar   spam    egg
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the last pipe / cat, you can redirect it to the file directly after tr

Can use your code like:

> egrep -Rl 'users.*log|log.*users' /home/moose/test | tr '\n' ' ' >
>   bigfile

This will give you:

> /home/moose/test/file1 /home/moose/test/2 /home/moose/test/3 
>   /home/moose/moose/file4

Comment: The problem with using `tr` rather than `paste` or `xargs` is that it also replaces the `\n` that terminates the line...and many tools that process text don't work properly if the final input line doesn't have a `\n` (they typically ignore that line).